# Multibit export private key to usb possible?

Tags: multibit

I have Multibit and want to export my private keys as a backup.

1) I cant see my external usb as a option when selecting a destination to export to.  Is this because cant export the private keys directly to a usb?

2) Once exported, is that it to make a back up of the private keys, or do you then have to re-import the private keys to transact in the wallet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Private keys can be exported to usb sticks or harddrives.
As for 2) when you export a private key for a back up or whatever else reason, you actually export a copy of the key . You original keys doesn't get moved out, so no, you don't neeed to re-import it.